# java Kafka send messages in docker is increasing open files (lsof ) at almost 50/sec

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, lsof

My java web application is running in docker container. Java application is sending messages to Kafka (~ 300 msgs/hour). The server is crashing very few hours. I need tot restart the server every  few hours at this time. I see that the number of open files are continuesly increasing. The output of below command is increasing ~ 50/sec

```
lsof |  grep kafka | wc -l
```

I have tried Kafka versions from 2.4.0 to 2.6.0. (both server and Kafka-client java) yet the problem persists.

**Java code **

```
public class KafkaProducer {
   
    private static KafkaProducer single_instance = null;

   
    public Producer<String, KafkaRequest> kafkaProducer = null;

   
    private KafkaProducer(String url)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", url);
         kafkaProducer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<>(props, new StringSerializer(), new KafkaRequestSerializer());
    }

   
    public static KafkaProducer getInstance(String url)
    {
        if (single_instance == null)
            single_instance = new KafkaProducer(url);

        return single_instance;
    }
```

}

**And sending message**

```
public void postKafkaMessage(String topicName, KafkaRequest kafkaRequest, String key, String kafkaUrl) {
    
            KafkaProducer kafkaProducer = KafkaProducer.getInstance(kafkaUrl);
            kafkaProducer.kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key, kafkaRequest));
        }
```

**Sample lsof snippets**

```
**COMMAND    PID  TID TASKCMD   USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME**
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  210u     IPv4              95985      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:37696->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  211u     sock                0,8      0t0    534942 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  212u     sock                0,8      0t0    534943 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  213r     FIFO               0,11      0t0     96862 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  214w     FIFO               0,11      0t0     96862 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  215u  a_inode               0,12        0      8697 [eventpoll]
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  216u     sock                0,8      0t0    531973 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  217u     IPv4              96864      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:37718->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  218u     sock                0,8      0t0    534027 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  219r     FIFO               0,11      0t0     95990 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  220w     FIFO               0,11      0t0     95990 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  221u  a_inode               0,12        0      8697 [eventpoll]
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  222u     sock                0,8      0t0    534028 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  223u     IPv4              95992      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:37728->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  224u     sock                0,8      0t0    534030 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  225r     FIFO               0,11      0t0     95994 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  226w     FIFO               0,11      0t0     95994 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  227u  a_inode               0,12        0      8697 [eventpoll]
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  228u     sock                0,8      0t0    534032 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  229u     IPv4              98150      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:37738->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  230u     sock                0,8      0t0    534944 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  231u     sock                0,8      0t0    532895 protocol: TCP
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  232r     FIFO               0,11      0t0     98838 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  233w     FIFO               0,11      0t0     98838 pipe
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  234u  a_inode               0,12        0      8697 [eventpoll]
java        23 1811 FlowRunne root  235u     sock                0,8      0t0    534035 protocol: TCP

java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  434u     IPv4             111060      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38250->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  440u     IPv4             112668      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38260->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  446u     IPv4             113865      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38270->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  452u     IPv4             111071      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38280->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  458u     IPv4             113871      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38290->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  464u     IPv4             113876      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38296->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  470u     IPv4             111080      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38308->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  476u     IPv4             112964      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38328->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)
java        23 1052 pool-8-th root  483u     IPv4             111102      0t0       TCP 7adf829e2db1:38340->kafka.server_elk:9092 (ESTABLISHED)


java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1189u     sock                0,8      0t0    614811 protocol: TCP
java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1190u     sock                0,8      0t0    622360 protocol: TCP
java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1191u     sock                0,8      0t0    536231 protocol: TCP
java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1192u     sock                0,8      0t0    622361 protocol: TCP
java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1193u     sock                0,8      0t0    536234 protocol: TCP
java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1194u     sock                0,8      0t0    536235 protocol: TCP
java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1195u     sock                0,8      0t0    616746 protocol: TCP
java        23  464 kafka-pro root 1196u     sock                0,8      0t0    616747 protocol: TCP
```

Comment: do you have Kafka server in the same container? If you have many partitions it can cause the issue

Comment: The kafka is running in a different container.  I have only one partition as the volume is very low.

Comment: I removed the singleton class and calling close() after every send message. This helped with the constant increasing of the open files.